# Is it possible to learn functional analysis without real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, soft-question

Are there parts in functional analysis that would be easier to learn without real analysis or is this just not possible?

When I say functional analysis I mean

1. Lebesgue measure and integral
2. spaces of Lebesgue integrable functions
3. Banach spaces
4. duality
5. bounded linear operator and linear operators in general
6. Hilbert space
7. reproducing kernel Hilbert space
8. non-linear analysis in Banach spaces

Comment: Well, a functional is a map into the base field. Might be a good idea to learn what happens in the base field.... You definitely can learn some functional analysis without real analysis, but they turn out to be very intertwined in that base fields of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are the ones you really want most of the time

Comment: What exactly is your goal in trying to learn Functional Analysis before any real analysis?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I updated my question. Does what I'm defining functional analysis to be i.-viii constitute functional analysis as you know it or are the topics I listed not really functional analysis?

Comment: Consider starting to read about what you need to learn. When you encounter things you don't understand, go back, figure those out, then read on.

Comment: I think that points 1 and 2 can't be learned without learning real analysis because they are part of real analysis.

Comment: Is knowing 1 and 2 sufficient to learn 3-8?

Comment: What do you mean by Real Analysis? Like undergrad real analysis as in Abbott's Understanding Analysis? My impression is that it would be quite difficult to dive into the more advanced topics on your list without already knowing the relatively easy material in Abbott. But I agree with Ethan Bolker that you can try diving in and then backtrack to fill in gaps.

Comment: @littleO I mean like Baby Rudin aka PMA that some undergraduates study.

Comment: My impression is that it would be rather difficult to learn these topics without first learning the first 7 chapters of baby Rudin. But I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen My goal was to understand support vector machines and the kernels used in them and convex optimization.

Comment: @Numbers Oh, in that case, you can possibly get by with much less, especially if you are doing more applied rather than theoretical machine learning research. How theoretical do you need to be? If you're doing applied machine learning, maybe you could just read the relevant sections of The Hundred Page Machine Learning Book (for example) and forget about learning real analysis and functional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Items 1 and 2 listed by you specifies Lebesgue measure and integrable functions.  It will be unwise to  try to understand them without having been exposed Riemann integral which is part of standard first course in  real analysis. That Lebesgue theory is  logically a generalisation and so usual Riemann integration is a special case is correct but only academically so.

Also textbooks of functional analysis are not written for people not exposed to real analysis. So it will be difficult to lern it.

It is possible to do mathematics by communicating with other mathematicians by writing letters (Euler, Newton, Fermat, Gauss did so). But you want a modern internet based forum now. And email and LaTeX all are needed though logically it is not a requirement. Now you decide how you should learn Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, what differentiates "Analysis" from other math regarding functions and the real or complex numbers etc, is the level of depth and rigor. You could probably learn something in each of the topics you listed, but it would be hard to understand the proofs or justification behind a lot of results. Consequently it's difficult to have a deep or truly meaningful understanding of functional analysis without real analysis experience.

Although there would maybe be more specific issues, like not being familiar with specific definitions and concepts stated in Theorems or otherwise. Again, you could learn these definitions but this boils down into what I said above.